# RegEx for matching URLs with 4-6 digits ID

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

I'm trying to match URLs that start with `"example.com/"` and are followed by 4-6 digits and the next character is not a digit (if there is a next character).

For example, `"example.com/12345"` should match.

`"example.com/1234567"` should *not* match.

`"example.com/123456g7"` should match.

I've tried `"example.com/(\d{4,6}).*"` but this matches when I give it `"example.com/1234567"` which is incorrect.

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

This expression adds additional boundaries just to safely pass your desired URLs:

```
^(https?:\/\/(www.)?)(example\.com)\/(?:[0-9]{4,6})?([a-z].*)?$
```

If you wish, you can reduce the boundaries. Here, we can add several capturing groups to be simple for calling.

`$` is the key that fails your undesired URL inputs.

[image]

#### RegEx

If this wasn't your desired expression, you can modify/change your expressions in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/0X3g00/1/).

#### RegEx Circuit

You can also visualize your expressions in [jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24):

[image]

#### JavaScript Demo

```js
const regex = /^(https?:\/\/(www.)?)(example\.com)\/(?:[0-9]{4,6})?([a-z].*)?$/gm;
const str = `http://example.com/12345
https://example.com/123456g7
http://www.example.com/12345
https://www.example.com/123456g7
http://www.example.com/12345
https://www.example.com/123456g7
http://www.example.com/123456adfasdfasdf98989898
https://www.example.com/123456g7adfadfa0909009
http://example.com/1234567
https://example.com/1234567`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

#### Python Test

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"^(https?:\/\/(www.)?)(example\.com)\/(?:[0-9]{4,6})?([a-z].*)?$"

test_str = ("http://example.com/12345\n"
    "https://example.com/123456g7\n"
    "http://www.example.com/12345\n"
    "https://www.example.com/123456g7\n"
    "http://www.example.com/12345\n"
    "https://www.example.com/123456g7\n"
    "http://www.example.com/123456adfasdfasdf98989898\n"
    "https://www.example.com/123456g7adfadfa0909009\n"
    "http://example.com/1234567\n"
    "https://example.com/1234567")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
    
    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))
    
    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1
        
        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

Answer (score 0):

Just negative lookahead for a digit after matching 4 to 6 digits:

```
example.com\/\d{4,6}(?!\d).*
```

https://regex101.com/r/YWmhgY/1/

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it.

`^example\.com/(\d{4,6})(?:\D.*)?$`

Comment: What does the colon in `(?:\D.*)` mean?

Comment: @user101 - It is part of a 3 character `(?:` beginning of a non-capture group construct. In this case it is used to tell the engine that it's contents `\D.*`, as a group are optional.